# Read posts from g+ fanpage using php (curl)

Tags: php, rest, curl, google-api, google-plus

I'm trying to read the latest posts from a g+ fanpage, using php. Alas, the documentation is not that helpful on how to do that :/

So far, I've tried the following:

```
<?php
$curlSession = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/{userID}/activities/public?key={apikey}');
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$jsonData = json_decode(curl_exec($curlSession));
curl_close($curlSession);
```

`{apikey}` and `{userID}` are placeholders, of course. I generated the api key via the Developers Console, neither server keys, nor browser keys make any difference to the result below.
The Google+ API is activated.

This is the result:

```
{
   "error":{
      "errors":[
         {
            "domain":"usageLimits",
            "reason":"accessNotConfigured",
            "message":"Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
         }
      ],
      "code":403,
      "message":"Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
   }
}
```

Do you have any suggestions on what's going wrong? Am I missing something?
Do I have to provide billing information for this kind of api request?

Comment: When you say "fanpage" do you mean a Google+ Community or a Google+ Page? (The distinction is important in this case.)

Comment: I'm talking about an official Google+ Page.

Answer (score 2):

It tells you right in the error message whats wrong ... `Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.`

Go Here https://code.google.com/apis/console/, on the left click on APIs & Auth, then turn on Google+ API and what ever other APIs you need

Comment: Hello, cmorrissey, :) Thanks for your answer! The Google+ Api for this project is already activated :/ I only want to get the information from the above URL, do I need to activate any additional API's? Cheers :)